# Modal window with jquery navigation inside

Tags: jquery, navigation, modalpopups

I am trying to set up a sites navigation which extends over several levels. I have built one option for the client where the different levels open using jquery and want to now see how this looks within a modal window.

However,

I am using FancyBox [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/) which I have used to load the navigation from an ajax call. It displays fine until you click to access the next layer which causes the window to close.

Any ideas how I can keep the window open until the user reaches the end point?

Help much appreciated.

EDIT:

apple have a slightly similar thing going on on the following page but with photos,

[Apple](http://www.apple.com/imac/design.html)

It all seems to be the same window not reloads like most modals.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here. Are you trying to open a modal and then open another on top of it? Could you clarify what you mean by levels and end point? If you could post code/link to your current version or draw a diagram that might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked out how best to do this, need to use the callbackonshow function that is built in to fancybox.